# Prove that for every positive integer $n, \exists c_n$ such that $f(c_n) = f(c_n+1/n)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f:[0,1] \to [0,1]$ be a continuous function with $f(0) = f(1)$. Prove that for every positive integer, $n, \exists c_n \in [0,1]$ such that $f(c_n) = f(c_n+1/n), c_n \in [0,1-\frac{1}{n}].$

With this problem, the only thing coming to my mind in terms of $n$ being a positive integer is that as $n$ goes to bigger and bigger, $f(c_n + \frac{1}{n})$ goes to closer and closer to $f(c_n + 0) = f(c_n),$ that's all. I can't come up anything in terms of using IVT to this. And, since $f(a) = f(b)$, I know I can't apply Rolle's theorem to this because the problem didn't say $f$ is differentiable. Any help? Thanks.

**Edit:** Even though the conditions are the same with [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/812407/a-forall-f-in-c0-with-f0-f1-there-exists-x-s-t-fxa-fx), the functions are still different. And, the answers for that question are clearly not helpful to solve my problem.

Comment: Can you do the case of $n=1$, perhaps? (Hint: Define $g(x)=f(x+\frac{1}2)-f(x)$)

Comment: @Meelo Ok, let me try and find out.

Comment: @Meelo I don't understand where/how can I apply n = 1, but the hint you've given: $g(x) = f(x+\frac{1}{x}) - f(x),$ can we then say, $g(a) \leq 0$ and $g(b) \geq 0, \exists c \in [a,b]$ such that $g(c ) = 0$ and hence the conclusion? But, then again, I don't know what $f(0)$ and $f(1)$ are to get the desired inequalities.

Comment: Oh, whoops. I meant $n=2$ - but yeah, the idea is we need to find an $a$ and a $b$ where $g$ is positive and negative respectively. The point here is that we know $f(1)-f(0)=0$ which is important - especially since, for instance $(f(\frac{1}2)-f(0))-(f(1)-f(\frac{1}2))=f(1)-f(0)$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider $g(x)=f(x+\frac{1}{n})-f(x)$ defined on $[0,1-\frac{1}{n}]$, assume there is no $x\in [0,1-\frac{1}{n}]$ such that $g(x)=0$ by intermediate value theorem ($g(x)$ continuous), we have either $g(x)>0$ or $g(x)<0$ for all $x\in [0,1-\frac{1}{n}]$. However, it makes $f(1)>f(1-\frac{1}{n})>…>f(0)$ or $f(1)<f(1-\frac{1}{n})<…<f(0)$, contradiction.

Comment: Why do you need a contradiction? Define $g$ that way, use IVT to find that it's $0$ for some number in the interval, and then the conclusion follows.

Comment: @RaceBannon How do you find that it is $0$ for some number in the interval?

Comment: It's continuous, so by the IVT, it hits every value in that interval. That's how.

Comment: @RaceBannon I guess it's not that simple frankooo's construction is very ingenious. $g$ could be positive everywhere and therefore would not have to hit $0$.

Comment: Where did $f(1-\frac{1}{n})$ come from?

Comment: $g(1-\frac{1}{n})>0$ so $f(1)>f(1-\frac{1}{n})$

Comment: or in the case $g(1-\frac{1}{n})<0$ that makes $f(1)<f(1-\frac{1}{n})$

Comment: Nice answer, I like it so much (+1).